# MultiValueDictKeyError at /files/ in Django file upload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am facing issue uploading file using Django rest framework.
I am testing using postman and adding Content-Type header as multipart/form-data, but I get

MultiValueDictKeyError at /files/ error, here is my code.

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def put(self,request, format = None):

        file_obj = request.FILES['file']

        file_obj.seek(0)
        data = file_obj.read()

        return Response(data,status=204)
```

I am using multipart form data so that I access post data along with uploading files.

Comment: Does it have a file named *file* (nnot some other error?)

Comment: I attached the file with the key as 'file'

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful to share the "calling mechanism" itself. The `MultiValueDictKeyError` suggests that it could not find the key (here `'file'`), and perhaps `print(..)` the keys of `request.FILE` (or set a breakpoint).

Comment: this is what get prints, {}

Comment: well then apparently the file is not "shipped", or at least not in a good way.

Comment: can you suggest a piece of code in which I can attach file and other post variables?

Answer (score 0):

I removed multipart/form-data from the header in postman and the API worked